# Erro Angular TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined em Table com 2 ngFor

Tags: angular

A lista esta funcionando perfeitamente, mas não consigo entender o porque do erro no console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Na imagem aparecem a tabela, o console e o array agrupado por medico.

Sou novato e autodidata e nem sei se usei o método correto para fazer este tipo de tabela ...

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
<ng-container *ngFor="let medico of consultas[0]">

    <thead>
        <tr class="bg-primary text-light">
            <th>Medico</th>
            <th>Paciente</th>
            <th>Data Agendada</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <p> <strong> {{medico.nomeMedico}} </strong> </p>

    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let consulta of medico.consultas">
            <td></td>
            <td>{{consulta.nome}}</td>
            <td>{{consulta.dataConsultaFrm}} - {{consulta.horaConsulta}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</ng-container>
</table>
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
var _ = require('lodash');

import { Consulta } from 'src/app/models/consulta.model';
import { ConsultaService } from 'src/app/services/consulta.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-consultas-listagem',
  templateUrl: './consultas-listagem.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./consultas-listagem.component.css']
})
export class ConsultasListagemComponent implements OnInit {

  consultas: Consulta[];

  constructor(
      private consultaService: ConsultaService
  ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.consultaService.getConsultas().subscribe( 
            consultas => { 
                var result = _(consultas)
                    .groupBy(x => x.nomeMedico)
                    .map((value, key) => ({nomeMedico: key, consultas: value}))
                    .value();
                this.consultas = Array.of(result);

                console.log(this.consultas);
            }
        );  
    }
}
```

[image: Tabela (OK), Erro Console e array agrupado]

Comment: Pensa um pouco comigo, se está fazendo um **for(*ngFor)** em `consultas`, para que o índice **`[0]`**?? Pode tbm dar uma lida no link para ver pq não deve perguntar e no lugar de código inserir imagens: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485

Comment: coloca o codigo do seu ts tambem, creio que o problema é que vc não esta inicalizando o array como um array vazio

Comment: coloca   consultas: Consulta[]=[]

Comment: Eduardo Vargas, acertou em cheio !!! Obrigado !!

Comment: Ola @Alexandre, Não altere o titulo da pergunta para indicar que seu problema foi resolvido. Se alguma reposta da comunidade te ajudou considere [aceitar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), essa é a melhor forma de agradecer quem te ajudou. Se você achou uma resposta diferente considere responder sua própria pergunta, isso pode ajudar a pessoas com o mesmo problema - [Posso responder minha própria pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). -- Vale a pena dar uma olhada em nosso [Tour]  =D

Answer (score 0):

Tenta inicializar sua propriedade como um array vazio

```
consultas: Consulta[] = [];
```